# Using regular expressions in Unix to find lines with numbers greater than 40000?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

So I think the first thing I need to do is make the first digit be greater than 4. If the first digit is found to be greater than 4 and the number is five digits or more, that number should be found. If the digit is 4, than one of the digits following has to be greater than 0. I'm really struggling on how to set this up. I don't know if I have all of the correct conditions, and the technical aspect of writing the regex is confusing me also. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using regular expressions for this? Iterate over the words in each line, and compare the word to the number 40000

```
awk '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
        if ($i > 40000) {
            print
            break
        }
}' file
```

Answer (score -1):

1. 5 Digit numbers - regex `[4-9][[:digit:]]{4}`
2. 6 or more digits - regex `[1-9][[:digit:]]{5,}` - Checks that the first digit is not zero!

Put it together

```
[4-9][[:digit:]]{4}|[1-9][[:digit:]]{5,}
```

Comment: When I run this in Terminal it says command not found. Any ideas why?

Comment: It is the regex. use `grep ' [4-9][:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{6,}' ...`. Read the manual page

Comment: This matches `42 igittigitt!` (using egrep). Testing advised :-)

Answer (score -1):

For greater *or equal* to 40000, use

```
 egrep '[4-9][[:digit:]]{4}|[[:digit:]]{6,}' file
```

Note extra brackets. `[:digit:]` is equivalent to one of the five characters in `dgit:`
Note further that the `{6,}` part will also match values less than 40000 if there are zero-padded numbers, such as `012345`.

For greater than 40000 the regex gets ugly if you don't want a second grep to just remove 40000 and glenn jackman's solution is what I recommend.

Comment: Nice cut'n'paste jobe from mine with the minor correction. (summat went wrong in the highlighting :-(

Comment: @EdHeal One person's minor correction is another person's two egregious bugs fixed. Character classes in ranges need the extra bracket AND alternatives with `|` and counts with `{n,}` are *extended* regexen, which won't work with standare grep, only with egrep. A simple `echo 40001|grep ...` is all it takes to demonstrate it won't work. I believe that this is the minimum QA and due diligence we should expect from answers. Especially if accompanied by advice to read the man page.

Comment: Depends on the version of grep.

Comment: @EdHeal Does it? All the grep man pages I've ever seen and POSIX require the `-E` option for grep to understand extended regexen. Can you name a specific OS where plain grep interprets them as extended?